# Is there a way to design Tinder/Twitter-self-profile-like header effect with table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to design something similar to what's seen on Tinder and Twitter own-profile view. There is a blurred background on Tinder behind user's own profile picture, and the view when swiped down, it grows and blur fades, ultimately arriving in user's profile view (and on Twitter, it starts sharp, and blurs as it grows bigger, resulting in Twitter account selection view). I've seen that particular effect on many apps lately, and I want to include it in my app too. Does that effect/gesture have a name? Is there an easy way to implement it with a standard table view, or should I start hard-coding it?

Comment: I suggest you to post an image to show the effect, so it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic design goes by various names such as `Parallax`, `Sticky Header`, or `Stretchy Header`.

The specific effect you're looking for is a **Parallax Blur**.

There are a few implementations at GitHub.  Here are two from [a quick search](http://github.com/search?q=parallax%20blur):

- [TwitterCover](http://github.com/cyndibaby905/TwitterCover) is a sharp image that blurs as the header grows.
- [ParallaxBlur](http://github.com/pyro2927/ParallaxBlur) is a blurred image that becomes sharper as the header grows.

Comment: this is what I exactly needed. thanks, it was hard to find it without knowing the name of the effect :)

Answer (score 17):

As an exercice i tried to reproduce the twitter profile header effect in the following project:
https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/twitterprofilepage

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea how to achieve such an sticky header with a `UIPageViewController` beneath? I mean you are using an UITableView which already has its `headerView` and sticky `sectionHeader`.

Comment: You mean a PageViewController instead of the table view?  What orientation for the page view controller? I am not sure to get how this should move, do you have an example of this type of effect?

Comment: I mean the segment control needs to change the pages below the header like in this example there is the scrollable `UITableView` but I am looking for a general `ViewController` with a sticky-scrollable-header that contains a `SegmentControl` which changes the content below the headers. Hard to explain. So the twitter app for example has those three segments "tweets", "photos"... but how do they change the content view/controller without changing the header. I think they're not just exchanging the `tableView` cells they do have other contents and layout there like a `PageViewController`.

Comment: If it was only 'tweets' and 'favorite', i'd say it's only changing the datasource and remember the contentOffset on switch. But 'photo' may be a collectionView and not a tableView. But since tableview and collectionview are so close, it may be just this?

Comment: Mh ya sounds logical however I have no idea how to implement that behavior with a smooth UI.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you should have a look at the 'Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views' talk of WWDC 2014 https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/.
They are talking about 'Global Headers', it's a great resource, there is sample code available.

Comment: Would this be able to be implemented with a pull to refresh feature in the tableview instead of zooming the image? If so, could you post some code for this?

Comment: 2 Daniel: Did you find a way to implement such twitter scrolling with UIPageViewController integrated to switch content below header? I'm experimenting trying to create a twitter profile UI, but have no success yet

Comment: Has this been modified for the new iPhone X format?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is putting two main objects on the view controller.One is UIViw,the other is UIScrollView(also UIScrollView subclass).You can put the UIView over the UIScrollView to mask the header part of the scrollview.Change the contenoffset of the scrollview(it's important especially when using the tableview, or the view will overlay the cell).The other thing is call the - (void)scrollviewdidscroll function.Do some math caculations in this function, mainly doing the parallax effect with scrollview.content.offset.y. This is an article introducing this—— 
[IMPLEMENTING THE TWITTER IOS APP UI (UPDATE: SWIFT 3)](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/)