# How can I use apple's standard controllers to reproduce this behaviour?

Tags: ios, user-interface, controller

I am trying to reproduce the following behaviour:

[image]
[image]

How can I do it? Any ideas?

I have tried in several different ways with no success so far.

Example: I have been trying to do this with a two section tableview being the first section header transparent (and a navigation bar at the same time) and the second section header a segmented control. But when I scroll down the first one doesn't float, hides.

Comment: You're trying to reproduce what behavior? There are several differences among the images you posted. What in them is the thing you're interested in?

Comment: I want to have a header view that shrinks and stays floating like a standard tableview section

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/pyro2927/ParallaxBlur to implement sample effect you have mentioned.

Comment: +1 it is a nice open source framework. Can you add the view on top of the header? (to simulate a navigationbar for instance)

Comment: Yes, @Dipen .. I ment directly, we no customisation

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library:

https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/twitterprofilepage

Original Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27740952/2584268

Content of Original Answer:

As an exercice i tried to reproduce the twitter profile header effect in the following project: https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/twitterprofilepage

[image]