# Parallax Header that zoom's the imageView on scroll?

Tags: objective-c, image, scroll, uitextfield

I have a view and I added scrollView to it, with an imageview and some textfileds. Now I want when I scroll the view down it zooms the image a bit and as I release the scroll view the imageview get back to it's original position. Just like tinder edit profile View. How to do that in Objective - C?

Answer (score 0):

There are many 3d party controls available for Parallax.

You can refer any one of them, you feel suitable.

You can refer these :

[Is there a way to design Tinder/Twitter-self-profile-like header effect with table view in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824165/is-there-a-way-to-design-tinder-twitter-self-profile-like-header-effect-with-tab)

https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader/blob/master/ParallaxTableViewHeader/ParallaxHeaderView.m